# Can't create a NuGet package when the directory structure contains spaces

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am trying to use Squirrel.Windows in my `AfterBuild` inside the csproj file to automatically create the installer. Because I was having a hard time getting relative paths to resolve, I decided to start specifying full paths. 
So, I have the following command

```
NuGet pack '$(ProjectDir)...\MyApp.TEST.nuspec' -Version %(myAssemblyInfo.Version) -Properties Configuration=Debug -OutputDirectory .\$(OutDir) -BasePath .\$(OutDir)
```

Which is resolving to this

```
NuGet pack 'C:\Users\pbg\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\...\MyApp.TEST.nuspec' -Version  -Properties Configuration=Debug -OutputDirectory .\bin\x86\TEST\ -BasePath .\bin\x86\TEST\
```

But, it's giving me the following error `pack: invalid arguments.`

I can only suspect that it's not liking the spaces, because I feel like tried everything else. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using double quotes and not single quotes?

Comment: And inside a MsBuild file, you'll need to escape those.

Comment: Using &quot; doesn't work either.